# Spring Turbine dashboard not working

Tags: hystrix, turbine

I am facing some issue while working on turbine dashboard. As I am able to get turbine stream for given cluster but not able to see anything on dashboard as it is just getting loaded as shown in below screenshots. Kindly help if any configuration is missing.

Below are my configurations:

config.properties

```
    turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=SpringHystrixDemo2
    turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=:9080/hystrix.stream
    turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.hystrix2.instances=localhost
    InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.class
    turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false
```

Application.yml

```
    server:
    port: 8080

    turbine:
    aggregator:
    clusterConfig: SPRINGHYSTRIXDEMO2
    clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
    appConfig: SpringHystrixDemo2

    InstanceMonitor:
    eventStream:
    skipLineLogic:
    enabled: false
```

bootstrap.yml

```
    spring:
    application:
    name: SpringTurbine
    cloud:
    config:
    discovery:
    enabled: true

    eureka:
    instance:
    nonSecurePort: ${server.port:8080}
    client:
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
```

Application.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableHystrix
    @EnableEurekaClient
    @EnableHystrixDashboard
    @EnableTurbine
    public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
```

For cluster SpringHystrixDemo2 I have configured it in different application running on other port:

application.yml -

```
    server:
    port: 9080

    hystrix:
    command:
    RemoteMessageClientCommand:
    execution:
    isolation:
    thread:
    timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
    RemoteMessageAnnotationClient:
    execution:
    isolation:
    thread:
    timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

bootstrap.yml

```
    spring:
    application:
    name: SpringHystrixDemo2
    cloud:
    config:
    enabled: true
    discovery:
    enabled: true
    serviceId: SPRINGCONFIGSERVER

    eureka:
    instance:
    nonSecurePort: ${server.port:9080}
    client:
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
```

Application.java - this is from hystrix dashboard service.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableHystrix
    @EnableHystrixDashboard
    @EnableEurekaClient
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
```

I have configured eureka server on 8761 port. which is lisening all other eureka client.as

[Eureka server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w9Kb.png)

This is how I am not able to see any turbine dashboard. as it is just getting loaded.
[turbine stream view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAz5A.png)

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is that you could declare a management endpoint like this:

```
management:
  port: 9081
  contextPath: /management
```

Then the turbine stream would be accesible via *{yourHost}:9081/management/turbine.stream*, while hystrix dashboard will be served under *{yourhost}:9080/hystrix*

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read and known, from your configuration

```
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=SpringHystrixDemo2
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=:9080/hystrix.stream
turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.hystrix2.instances=localhost    InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.class
turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false
```

following maybe the problem(s).

You are short of a few configs and maybe you have some extra configs too.

1. You do not need "turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.hystrix2.instances" unless you really have multiple instances.
2. You do not need "turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled" because its false by default, and its required if you want it to be true when u you have high latency.
3. you need "turbine.appConfig=". In your case i think its something like SpringHystrixDemo2 or maybe hystrix2 ... use proper name here.
4. you need "turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=" which worked for me only when i used in CAPITAL i.e. HYSTRIX2
5. if you are using different management port on your service, "turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.HYSTRIX2=:/hystrix.stream
6. then this "turbine.instanceInsertPort=false" will disable default port insertion by turbine.. basically, you are telling eureka not to insert any port on its own when trying to search for hystrix.strem..

following are my properties.

```
#turbine.clusterNameExpression=new String('default')
#turbine.clusterNameExpression="'default'"
turbine.instanceInsertPort=false
turbine.appConfig=service1
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=SERVICE1
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.SERVICE1=:51512/hystrix.stream
#turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.USER.instances=service1-host1.abc.com,service1-host2.abc.com
InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.class
#for high latencies
#turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false
```

and try the turbine stream on

```
http://host:port/turbine.stream?cluster=SERVICE1
```